# javascript: parsing variables in the URL

Tags: javascript, regex

so, my URL is example.com/?ref=person

but ref is null after the regex. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function getReferer(){
    var regex = new RegExp(/ref=(.+)/);
    var ref = regex.exec(window.location.ref);
    alert(ref);
    if (ref == null) return "";
    else return ref[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `window.location.ref` by `window.location.href`.
Don't use `new RegExp` if not necessary, it's slower.

```
function getReferer(){
    var regex = /ref=(.+)/;
    var ref = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    alert(ref);
    if (ref == null) return "";
    else return ref[1];
}
```